# How to Pass an Imap Connection from PHP Imap Library from PHP/JQuery to PHP File

Tags: php, jquery, imap

I would like to be able to pass a an Imap file named $connection from 1 php file to another php file using Jquery. The issue is, It doesn't pass as the object, it gets converted to a string called resource #54 - Is there any possible way to pass the Imap Connection object to another PHP file?  I really need to keep this connection open because if I repeatedly close it and open new connections, providers such as Hotmail and Yahoo lock us out for 15-30 minutes.

Here's my current code Jquery w/ PHP variables mixed in:

```
    var dataString='server=<?php echo $server; ?>&email=<?php echo $email_address; ?>&connection=<?php echo $connection; ?>&password=<?php echo $password; ?>&server=<?php echo $server;?>&daysago='+daysago+'&num='+num;
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
    url: "fastsearch.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(msg){
```

Is it possible or conceivable to pass this variable to a php file using jquery or something other than jquery?  If not, what are my options for a workaround?  Is it possible to display results without ending a PHP file?

Here's more info on imap_open & the imap stream object:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open.php

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "pass" a connection between scripts as they are spawned under seperate server processes so after it completes there is no reference to it.  What you need to do is open up a persistent connection to the imap server using [pfsockopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pfsockopen.php):

```
$f = pfsockopen('an.imap_server.com', 143)
```

You will then construct the essential imap commands by hand and use `fputs` to post to the open connection:

```
$query = 'LOGIN ' . strlen($user) . "}\r\n" . $user ... 
fputs($f, $query)
```

and so on.

Comment: Thanks so Do you know how I would do that with imap?  Because I need to enter a username and password.  Here's the usual syntax I use:   $connection = imap_open($server,$login,$password);

Comment: Also, I think pfsockopen() is the function I should be looking for, not fsockopen()

Comment: Awesome thanks - you mind sharing a link or two so I can read more about this?

Comment: Thanks - I found this resource, but I'm not 100% sure how to use the search function - I'm going to search now for a more detailed website with the fputs and imap commands - http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=295562.0

Comment: Any idea on the syntax for search using fputs?

Comment: pfsockopen works like the other persistent resource connection types: it creates a resource and you still can't pass a resource between scripts. Also there's a lot more chance that an imap connection might be used with multiple different accounts - and the persistent resources are stored in a pool referenced by type and account - although if its only one/few accounts it might be an option - the only problem is building the rest of the protocol stack

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass resources between separate instances of PHP scripts.

The answer by Wes is sort of correct - but do read the discussion.

If it were me I'd use a daemon/scheduled job to fetch the mail - while you could write your own in PHP, I'd just use [fetchmail](http://fetchmail.berlios.de/) and cron to get the email off the remote system then either mirror it in a local mailbox or feed it through procmail.